# Правильное использование адаптера в ListView

Tags: массивы, listview, android

Такой вопрос: стоит задача получить с сервера данные в json {"payload":[{'id': 101, 'name': 'имя1'}, {'id': 293, 'name': 'имя3'}, ... ],"resultCode":"OK"} и запихнуть их в ListView так, чтобы при клике по пункту переходить в следующую активность, передав ей реальный id записи. И хотелось бы их отображать, не сохраняя на телефоне.
Никак не могу понять как правильно это сделать. Может кто-нибудь подсказать как такую задачу правильно реализовать?

Comment: правильнее - написать свой адаптер, да и в SimpleAdapter ты передаешь data - пустой ArrayList

Comment: Сделала следующим образом:
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_test, values); 
   llTest.setAdapter(adapter);

Как теперь в values поместить полученные значения?

Answer (score 2):

Статей в интернете на эту теме - [вагон](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) и [тележка](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/).

Правда, мне больше нравиться вариант с [asyncTask](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-json-parsing-with-jsonobject-and-loading-to-listview-example/).